# How to post an image to facebook timeline from android app WITHOUT SHOWING DIALOG

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am working on facebook sharing module in my app, I want to post an image to my timeline(wall) from my app, but I want to do this without any dialog, I have searched lot of links which show code using deprecated methods with no luck, Can anybody help me for this? thanks in advance.

```
public  void postImageonWall(String msg ) {

            String path = "me/feed";
            AccessToken at = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Const.bmp_post.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] bytearray = stream.toByteArray();
            parameters.putByteArray("picture", bytearray);
            HttpMethod method = HttpMethod.POST;
            GraphRequest.Callback cb = new GraphRequest.Callback() {



                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {

                    //check graphResponse for success or failure
                    if(graphResponse.getError()==null){
                        Toast.makeText(NewPostActivity.this, "Successfully posted to Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(NewPostActivity.this, "Facebook: There was an error, Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            };

            GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(at,path,parameters,method,cb);
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ;




    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to go with Graph Api.
You need to convert your image into byte array and then you can go this way:

```
    String path = "me/feed";
    AccessToken at = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putByteArray("picture", bytearray);
    HttpMethod method = HttpMethod.POST;
    GraphRequest.Callback cb = new GraphRequest.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {

            //check graphResponse for success or failure
            if(graphResponse.getError()==null){
                Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Successfully posted to Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Facebook: There was an error, Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    };

    GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(at,path,parameters,method,cb);
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
```

Comment: Hello Chintan thanks for reply,can you help me little more,I am getting this error,`{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#100) picture is not properly formatted}}` .. What need to do to resolve it?

Comment: @sulphuricAcid are you sure about authentication ? Is it authenticated ?

Comment: @sulphuricAcid can you try using JPG compression instead of PNG ?